# ASP.NET MVC controller method input parameter - how does it get populated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to understand an ASP.NET MVC JQGrid sample. The grid makes an AJAX request to get its data:

```
http://[thesiteurl]/[ControllerName]/GetGridData?_search=false&nd=14&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Id&sord=asc
```

The controller method is:

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(GridSettings gridSettings)
```

How do the GET params get transformed into a GridSettings object, and how can it be changed with a different type?

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET MVC framework has a built-in model binder which performs this task.  (You can write custom model binders as well.)  Essentially what it does at its simplest is examine the key/value pairs of incoming data and match it with the method parameters of the routed action method.

Examining the request, it looks like you have the following:

```
_search: false
nd: 14
rows: 10
page: 1
sidx: Id
sord: asc
```

So, for example, if the `Gridsettings` object is defined like this:

```
class GridSettings
{
    public string _search { get; set; }
    public int nd { get; set; }
    public int rows { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string sidx { get; set; }
    public string sord { get; set; }
}
```

Then the model binder would be able to map the incoming parameters to the model's properties accordingly.

If you were to define another type with the same properties then you could use that type in place of `GridSettings`.  With that type you could add more properties to match any client-supplied values you want to add, you could add more logic internal to the model, etc.